# hub.get_expected_image_size generates an error

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-hub

I am trying to determine the expected image size a tensorflow classifier model.  From

https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/tutorials/image_feature_vector

this is accomplished by

```
   image_module = hub.Module('https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/mobilenet_v2_035_128/feature_vector/2')
   image_size = hub.get_expected_image_size(image_module)
```

I have a locally located model imagenet/inception/resnet/v2/classification/4 that I am trying.  My code is

```
    export_path = "/home/adi/Desktop/oni/tensor_flow/tf_model_clas/imagenet_inception_resnet_v2_classification_4/"
    module_spec = hub.load_module_spec(export_path)
    height, width = hub.get_expected_image_size(model_spec)
    print(height,width)
```

With this code, I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./evaluate_models_class.py", line 203, in <module>
    height, width = hub.get_expected_image_size(classifier_model)
  File "/home/adi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_hub/image_util.py", line 77, in get_expected_image_size
    image_module_info = get_image_module_info(module_or_spec)
  File "/home/adi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_hub/image_util.py", line 54, in get_image_module_info
    return module_or_spec.get_attached_message(
AttributeError: '_UserObject' object has no attribute 'get_attached_message'
```

I obtain a functional model when I load it with

```
    classifier_model = keras.models.load_model(export_path)
    classifier = tf.keras.Sequential([hub.KerasLayer(classifier_model)])
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

hub.get_expected_image_size only works for some models in Hub.Module format that were exported in a certain way, this function will not work on TF2 SavedModels.